# Add lower and upper limit specification vertical lines on histogram with DENEB [VEGA-LITE]

Tags: powerbi, statistics, histogram, vega-lite, deneb

[image]

Hello!
I am working with data analysis on Power BI. Since recently the platform removed the Histogram Chart I am trying to work with Deneb, a custom visual based on Vega-lite.
I would like to build a histogram, with mean, lower specification limit (LSL) and upper specification limit (USL).
My results are dynamic , since there are many products I am working with. Each product has analysis like pH, weight, concentration, etc, and each analysis has its own LSL and USL (ex: pH 7.0 to 8.5, concentration 1,3 to 2,9 % and weight 120 to 300 mg, all for product A).

I watched the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67ucnNrMHgY, which really helped me!
But I still am not able to add LSL and USL, because I am new in Vega-lite world.

```json
{
  "description": "Histogram",
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "color": "#377eb8",
        "tooltip": true
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "RESULTS",
          "bin": {"maxbins": 10
          },
          "title": "RESULTS"
        },
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "count",
          "title": "ABSOLUTE FREQUENCE"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "aggregate": "mean",
          "field": "RESULTS"
          },
          "color": {"value": "red"},
          "size": {"value": 3}
        }
    }
              ]
    }
```

[image]

How can I add vertical lines with my limits? They are measures on Power BI. I can't fix a value, because the value change according with analyasis.

[How to add vertical Rule with constant value to Vega Lite chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61977413/how-to-add-vertical-rule-with-constant-value-to-vega-lite-chart) This question is similar to mine, but didn't helped me, unfortunatelly.

Comment: Can you share a .pbix?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the measures with the USL and LSL into the visual and reference them in the rule mark in the Vega spec.

[image: Power BI Visualizations pane]

[image: Final histogram]

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "layer": [
    {
      "description": "Histogram bars",
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "color": "#7DA7D9",
        "stroke": "#515151",
        "strokeWidth": 1,
        "tooltip": true
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "RESULTS",
          "bin": {"maxbins": 10},
          "title": "RESULTS"
        },
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "count",
          "field": "RESULTS",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "ABSOLUTE FREQUENCE"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "description": "Histogram line",
      "transform": [
        {
          "density": "RESULTS",
          "bandwidth": 5,
          "as": ["values", "density"]
        }
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "color": "#931313",
        "strokeWidth": 3,
        "tooltip": true
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "values",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "density",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": null
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "description": "USL line",
      "mark": {
        "type": "rule",
        "strokeDash": [20, 10]
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "USL",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "color": {"value": "#CE0000"},
        "size": {"value": 2}
      }
    },
    {
      "description": "USL label",
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "center",
        "fontWeight": 100,
        "color": "#CE0000"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "USL",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {"value": -10},
        "text": {"value": "USL"}
      }
    },
    {
      "description": "LSL line",
      "mark": {
        "type": "rule",
        "strokeDash": [20, 10]
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "LSL",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "color": {"value": "#CE0000"},
        "size": {"value": 2}
      }
    },
    {
      "description": "LSL label",
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "center",
        "fontWeight": 100,
        "color": "#CE0000"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "LSL",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {"value": -10},
        "text": {"value": "LSL"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {
    "scale": {"y": "independent"}
  }
}
```